# Overwrite the column when change the column type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, one of the column have datatype "BIGINT" let's say - OId,
my query

```
SELECT *, CAST(CAST(OId AS bigint) AS nvarchar) as OId
FROM Order
```

when i run it it created another column OId_1, 
here is the question how to overwrite existing column OId with OId_1 ?
one conditions - in select i should have '*'.

My expected output OId with datatype - nvarchar

Thanks

Comment: Why not give the new column a different alias `cast (...) as oid_new`?

Comment: You need to manually specify every column.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you have to list all the columns you want:

```
SELECT o.col1, o.col2, . . .,
       CAST(CAST(OId AS bigint) AS nvarchar(255)) as OId
FROM Order o;
```

Note:  You should never use the character types without a length in SQL Server.  The default varies by context, and sometimes leaving out the length can result in very-hard-to-debug errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like below :

```
SELECT o.ColumnA, o.ColumnB,...
       CAST(CAST(OId AS bigint) AS nvarchar(200)) as OId
FROM Order o
```